PhpStorm. Open all (modal) windows maximized/full screen
Is it possible to open (modal) windows in PhpStorm maximized or full screen by default? E.g. Settings, Search Anywhere, Find in Files, Recent Files, Rollback Changes etc.
Where exactly in PhpStorm are the window size and position settings stored after the window has been manually resized?


"Is it possible to open (modal) windows in PhpStorm maximized or full screen by default?" As far as I know  -- No



"Where exactly in PhpStorm are the window size and position settings stored after the window has been manually resized?" Good question. It used to be a single location in the past, but for a while each project seem to have own sizes.


So the "global" / "old" (??) location is in the IDE-wide settings folder -- check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory A file named window.state.xml (on windows that would be in options subfolder). From what I see it has some positions / sizes based on the display/screen size (I'm using 2K monitor for 3 or 4 years now, but it still has references to my old smaller but wider screen. So this is unlikely the file you are after.

Since such screens can have different sizes per project... this info is stored in a workspace file, but the file name is dynamic (unique for each project). 1) Open your workspace.xml file from the PROJECT_ROOT/.idea/ folder (this specific project settings). 2) Locate there a node for ProjectId, for example <component name="ProjectId" id="1OVsD6SX2AzSazagHBXOTEBLIaW" /> 3) Go to the IDE-wide settings folder (see prev comment) and look for workspace folder there.


Once inside -- locate a file with that ID as a name -- 1OVsD6SX2AzSazagHBXOTEBLIaW.xml in my example. 5) Look at values in the <component name="WindowStateProjectService"> node. P.S. Any edits should be done when that project is closed, of course. As the file gets written when closing the project / ending the IDE session.


Reading through https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-123462/Make-dialogs-to-be-maximizable-on-Windows, I just tried Win+Up on my Windows IntelliJ Idea. Guess what - it (almost completely) maximized that modal commit dialog window! That's a Windows thing, though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/customize/predefined-key-combinations#shell-keys - but it helps!

Maybe there is a similar maximize window system shortcut for Macos - e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/1744535/are-there-any-keyboard-shortcuts-to-minimize-or-maximize-a-window-in-macos ?
